# KivyMD How to add images in the Lists items from py?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I know that I can add images or icons to the items of the list in the kivy file. For example:

```
ScrollView:
    MDList:
        id: elements_list_container
        TwoLineAvatarListItem:
            text: "Hello World"
            secondary_text: "Secondary text"
            ImageLeftWidget:
                source: "image.png"
```

However, if I create the list from the python file, I dont know how to add those images and how to add functionallity whene is clicked. I just know how to add text:

```
for i in range(20):
    items = TwoLineListItem(text="Producto" + str(i), secondary_text="Categoria",)
    self.ids.elements_list_container.add_widget(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

````py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import IRightBodyTouch, OneLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons


KV = '''
<ListItemWithCheckbox>:

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon

    RightCheckbox:


MDBoxLayout:

    ScrollView:

        MDList:
            id: scroll
'''


class ListItemWithCheckbox(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    '''Custom list item.'''

    icon = StringProperty("android")


class RightCheckbox(IRightBodyTouch, MDCheckbox):
    '''Custom right container.'''


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        icons = list(md_icons.keys())
        for i in range(30):
            self.root.ids.scroll.add_widget(
                ListItemWithCheckbox(text=f"Item {i}", icon=icons[i])
            )


MainApp().run()```
````